# Unable to invoke a method with generic enum type as parameter

Tags: c#-4.0, generics, enums

I have a helper method which puts in spaces into enum names like below.

```
 public static string GetListItemString(Enum listItem)
        {
            string result = string.Empty;

#region ELegalStatus
            if (listItem is ELegalStatus)
            {
                switch ((ELegalStatus) listItem)
                {
                    case ELegalStatus.PrivateLimited:
                        result = "Private Limited";
                        break;
                    case ELegalStatus.PublicLimited:
                        result = "Public Limited";
                        break;
                   }
             }
#endregion


#region ERegion
            if (listItem is ERegion)
            {
                switch ((ERegion) listItem)
                {
                    case ERegion.EnglandandWales:
                        result = "England and Wales";
                        break;
                    case ERegion.NorthernIreland:
                        result = "Northern Ireland";
                        break;
                    case ERegion.Scotland:
                        result = "Scotland";
                        break;
                }
            }
            #endregion 

      return result;
    }
```

And I am in the process of creating a method to convert an enum into list, which is as follows.

```
public static object EnumToList<T>()
        {
            Type enumType = typeof (T);

            // Can't use type constraints on value types, so have to do check like this
            if (enumType.BaseType != typeof (Enum))
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("T must be of type System.Enum");
            }

            Array enumValArray = Enum.GetValues(enumType);

            foreach (var name in enumValArray)
            {
                var y = Enum.Parse(enumType, name.ToString().Trim(), true);                

               var x = ListHelper.GetListItemString(y);

            }

         return null;

        }
```

In the above method when all the names/values of a generic enum are read into the array, I would like to iterate though each of them and invoke the method 'GetListItemString' to get the properly spaced version of the name.

But as 'GetListItemString' method only accepts a 'Enum' type it is not compiling.

I am not sure how to pass in the required parameter for this method while iterating through the name/values of the enum.

Could someone please help?

**Update:** I already tried using var x = ListHelper.GetListItemString((Enum) y);

But the value of x is always empty when the 'EnumToList' method is invoked using EnumToList();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to cast from `object` to `Enum`, as the return type of `Parse` is `object` for some reason.

```
var x = ListHelper.GetListItemString((Enum) y);
```

You might also want to check out (and possibly alter) my [Unconstrained Melody project](https://code.google.com/p/unconstrained-melody/) which provides a workaround for the generic constraints issue.

Comment: Casting y to 'Enum' does make it compile, but the 'GetListItemString' does not return anything if you are calling the method like this 'EnumToList<ELegalStatus>();'

Comment: @kranthi: Well it's got to return *something*. Are you saying it returns an empty string? If so, you should really start debugging into it... it's much easier for you to do so than us. Debug through it line by line - check the value of `y` beforehand, etc.

Comment: I debugged it.the resulting value of casting 'y' to 'Enum' is not considered as of type 'ELegalStatus' by the 'GetListItemString' method and that case is not executed, hence the empty string.

Comment: @kranthi: It's not clear what you mean. Did you check the value of `y` *before* the cast? If the cast failed, I'd expect an exception... (If you can convert your code into a short but *complete* example, I'd happily try to reproduce the problem.)

Comment: Not Sure, Why it did not work yesterday. But today when I tried to create an example for you, it started working.As far as I know, I did not make any changes to get it working. Anyways, thanks for your help.